# Ajax return var with server response

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, response

I have this function, just make a simple request to the server, simply AJAX.

```
( function() {
'use strict';
Request  = { 
    Call: function ( u, theme, params ) { 
      var ajax, t; ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
      ajax.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) { 
          this.Reponse = ajax.responseText; 
        } 
      }; 
      if ( theme == 'POST' ) { 
        ajax.open('POST', u, true); 
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        ajax.send(params); 
      } 
      else { 
        if ( theme == 'GET' ) { 
          ajax.open('GET', u, true); 
          ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
          ajax.send(null); 
        }  
      } 
    },
    Response : null
  } 
})();
```

I want to store the server's response into a variable, like this :

```
window.onLoad = function () {
  Request.call('post.php', 'POST', 'bar=foo');
  //then
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = Ajax.Request.Response;
}
```

Because I want to process the response separately.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Don't the last 4 lines of the code cause a race condition? You're accessing the value of your ajax call immediately after sending it off. What happens if there's a delay?

Comment: Then i will verify if the status === 200, no?

Comment: You'll actually need to verify the readystate.

Comment: but what I need is to store the response in an object, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) { 
          this.Reponse = ajax.responseText; 
        }
```

with

```
if(ajax.readyState == 4) { 
          yourfunction(ajax.responseText);
}
[...]
function yourfunction(var response) {
      //use variable response here
}
```

Comment: What harm does this.Response bring?

Comment: But I want to assign the response in a object

`code
( function(){
'use strict';
var Request = {};
Request.Call : function () {
  //..//
    if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) {
      this.Response = ajax.responseText;
  //..//
};
Request.Response : null;

} )();
code`

Comment: you could call the function after that, ill update the code above

Comment: of course don't copy the [...] just put the function yourfunction() ... before the other functions.

Comment: But if I call the function, like that :

window.onLoad = function () {
  Request.call('post.php', 'POST', 'bar=foo');
  //then
  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = Ajax.Request.Response( // MISSING PARAM );
}

This will return an error :s

Answer (score 0):

You can access the response using `responseText`

```
var response = ajax.responseText
```